# Translate Image with respect to its centroid

Tags: image-processing, geometric-transform

To apply DistanceTransform for shape recognition, I want to center all images in a fixed point `{cx,cy}`. I mean each image's centroid should be  `{cx,cy}`.
I am using this code but It does not wrok.

```
{cx,cy}={50,50}.
cen=ComponentMeasurements[im1, "Centroid"][[All, 2]]
ImageTransformation[im1, (# + {cx, cy} - cen) &]
```

What is wrong?

[image: im1]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
im1 = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/78jWB.png"];
{cx, cy} = {50, 50};
cen = ComponentMeasurements[im1, "Centroid"][[All, 2]][[1]];

im2 = ImageForwardTransformation[im1, (# + {cx, cy} - cen) &, DataRange -> Full];
(* or ImageForwardTransformation[im1, TranslationTransform[{cx, cy}-cen], DataRange -> Full] *)

im3 = ImageTransformation[im1, (# - {cx, cy} + cen) &, DataRange -> Full];
(* or ImageTransformation[im1, TranslationTransform[cen - {cx, cy}],  DataRange -> Full]*)

Row[{im1, im2, im3 }, Spacer[3]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I understand inversely the function!!!

Comment: @Developer2000, my pleasure. Thank you for the Accept.